# Adding statistical weight to reviews

Tags: statistics

I'm trying to prioritize a list of places using a few factors:

1. Number of reviews for each place
2. Percent of people that recommend each place (from the pool of people that reviewed)
3. Overall rating of each place (from 0 to 5 stars)

I'm pretty sure that rating should not count for much until a significant amount of people have actually reviewed each place. I want to produce a ranking for each place and put the "best" at the top.

Answer (score 1):

A relatively simple way to adjust for the number of reviews is to divide all rankings for all locations by 5, so your scores are normalized rankings $r_i$, then calculate for each location, $i$, calculate the average normalized ranking, $\bar r_i$ and assign each location the following score:

$y_i=\frac{\bar r_i-b}{\nu_i n_i+2}$ - this is a modified version of the Agresti-Coull estimator of a binomial proportion.he parameter $\nu_i$ determines how much weight you give to reach reviewer. It's value in the Agresti-Coull estimator is $1$, but that means that after you have 10 reviews or so, you are basically just doing a naive averaging of the results.

If you suspect that there is some gaming (as John suggested above), then you may want to set $\nu_i<1$, or example, if you think that a significant minority of people, say $30\%$ are not accurately representing their thoughts, then you may want to set $\nu_i$ to $1-30\%=70\%$ so that your effective sample size corrects somewhat for the smaller number of truthful reviews. Estimating this is hard, but you can get a sense of this from the "variability" of the normalized reviews compared to what you would get if people were just randomly guessing (i.e. $Var_0[r_i]$):

$Var_0[r_i] = \frac{1}{6}\sum\limits_{j=0}^{5} \left(\frac{j}{5}-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\approx 0.23$

Your sample variance for the normalized scores for location $i$ is $s^2_i=\frac{1}{n_i-1}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n_i} (r_{ij}-\bar r_i)^2$

You could set $\hat \nu_i=\frac{Var_0[r_i]}{s^2_i}$ so that higher levels of inconsistency in the scores reduces the value of each cores, but high consistency increases value of each vote.

Finally, $b$ is the expected bias, which you could estimate by examining the value of $y$ for $N$ locations where you feel you could give your own ranking $R_k \in \{1...5\}$. Let $\hat b_k$ be the difference between $y_k$ (with $b_k=0$) and $\frac{R_k}{5}$:$\hat b_k = y_k|_{b_k=0} -\frac{R_k}{5}$. You can weight each $\hat b_k$ by the number of reviewers for location $k$, so that $\hat b = \frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{m=i}^{N} n_m \hat b_k$.

The "adjusted" score for each location is then just $5y_i|_{\hat \nu_i,\hat b}$. T

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it.  What you state as criteria are reasonable.

You can make things count on a linear scale, a sliding scale, a logarithmic scale, etc.  You can apply thresholds -- that is, a place doesn't even make the list until it gets $x$ reviews.

You might also consider reviewer ratings.  How much does your community trust a particular reviewer?

And whatever you arrive at for your answer, expect it to be gamed.  It's surprisingly inexpensive to buy good reviews.

You can do this by getting feedback on the review.  Was the review helpful or not?

(Gee, this is starting to look a lot like Amazon's model!)

But the short answer is you'll need some score to rack and stack.  You'll want the score to be competitive, meaning that it should be reasonable for competitors to ... well ... compete for good rankings.  Unless there's overwhelming evidence that one place is far better than all the others.